# TypeError: Cannot read property 'default' of undefined

Tags: node.js, webpack, babeljs

I am trying to get my Node project to work with Webpack and Babel. I am currently running into this issue when I try to do `npm run server`.
[image: PowerShell error]
As text:

```
(node:13340) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: Cannot read property 'default' of undefined
    at C:\Users\1silv\OneDrive\Documents\Senior Project\Sage\server.js:106608:67
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:68:7)
(node:13340) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). (rejection id: 1)
(node:13340) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
(node:13340) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: Cannot read property 'default' of undefined
    at C:\Users\1silv\OneDrive\Documents\Senior Project\Sage\server.js:106608:67
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:68:7)
(node:13340) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). (rejection id: 2)
webpack built 0d416d43c5c5733e2a92 in 5978ms
× ｢wdm｣: Hash: 0d416d43c5c5733e2a92
Version: webpack 4.0.0
Time: 5978ms
Built at: 3/21/2019 4:11:26 PM
    Asset      Size  Chunks                    Chunk Names
server.js  25.9 MiB     app  [emitted]  [big]  app
Entrypoint app [big] = server.js
[./node_modules/ejs/lib/ejs.js] 26 KiB {app} [built] [2 warnings]
[./node_modules/google-auth-library/build/src/index.js] 1.67 KiB {app} [built]
[./node_modules/mariadb/promise.js] 938 bytes {app} [built]
[./node_modules/moment/moment.js] 147 KiB {app} [built]
[./node_modules/plaid/lib/plaid.js] 492 bytes {app} [built]
[./node_modules/webpack-dev-middleware/index.js] 2.32 KiB {app} [built]
[./node_modules/webpack/lib/webpack.js] 7.71 KiB {app} [built]
[./server2.js] 26.3 KiB {app} [built]
[./webpack.config.js] 858 bytes {app} [built]
[child_process] external "child_process" 42 bytes {app} [built]
[fs] external "fs" 42 bytes {app} [built]
[http] external "http" 42 bytes {app} [built]
[https] external "https" 42 bytes {app} [built]
[util] external "util" 42 bytes {app} [built]
   [0] multi ./server2.js 28 bytes {app} [built]
    + 1998 hidden modules
```

Here is the line that it says is causing the error:

```
/***/ "./node_modules/loader-runner/lib/loadLoader.js":
/*!******************************************************!*\
  !*** ./node_modules/loader-runner/lib/loadLoader.js ***!
  \******************************************************/
/*! no static exports found */
/***/ (function(module, exports, __webpack_require__) {

var LoaderLoadingError = __webpack_require__(/*! ./LoaderLoadingError */ "./node_modules/loader-runner/lib/LoaderLoadingError.js");

module.exports = function loadLoader(loader, callback) {
    if(true) {
        __webpack_require__("./node_modules/loader-runner/lib lazy recursive")(loader.path).catch(callback).then(function(module) {
            loader.normal = typeof module === "function" ? module : module.default; // <-----This is the line
            loader.pitch = module.pitch;
            loader.raw = module.raw;
            if(typeof loader.normal !== "function" && typeof loader.pitch !== "function") {
                return callback(new LoaderLoadingError(
                    "Module '" + loader.path + "' is not a loader (must have normal or pitch function)"
                ));
            }
            callback();
        });
    } else { var retry, module; }
};
```

Running `npx webpack` only yields a bunch of warnings, but when I run `npm run server`, it gives the same warnings and a bunch of errors like this:
[image: Error]
All of the `../../` makes me wonder if it's trying to use a global npm package, but I think I have gotten rid of all of those.

It also can't compile my own `.js` files:
[image: Error]
I can confirm that the file `index.js` is in that folder.

Here is my `webpack.config.js` file:

```
const path = require('path');
const webpack = require('webpack');

module.exports = {
    target: 'node',
    mode: 'development',
    entry: {
        app: ['./server2.js']
    },
    devtool: 'inline-source-map',
    devServer: {
        contentBase: './',
        hot: true
    },
    plugins: [
        new webpack.HotModuleReplacementPlugin()
    ],
    output: {
        filename: 'server.js',
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, './'),
        publicPath: '/'
    },
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: '/\.js$/',
                exclude: /node_modules/,
                use: {
                    loader: 'babel-loader',
                    options: {
                        presets: ['@babel/preset-env']
                    }
                }
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

Here is `.babelrc`:

```
{
    "presets": [
        [
            "@babel/preset-env",
            {
                "targets": {
                    "node": true
                }
            }
        ]
    ]
}
```

And here is package.json:

```
{
  "name": "sage-savings",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "description": "An app for easy budgeting.",
  "main": "webpack.config.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "watch": "webpack --watch",
    "build": "webpack --config webpack.config.js",
    "server": "node server.js",
    "start": "webpack-dev-server --open"
  },
  "author": "Dakota Dalton",
  "repository": "https://github.com/1silvertiger/Sage",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "@types/express": "^4.16.1",
    "aws-sdk": "^2.422.0",
    "body-parser": "^1.18.3",
    "config": "^3.0.1",
    "cors": "^2.8.5",
    "ejs": "^2.6.1",
    "express": "4.16.x",
    "express-session": "^1.15.6",
    "google-auth-library": "^3.1.0",
    "mariadb": "^2.0.3",
    "moment": "^2.24.0",
    "mysql": "^2.16.0",
    "plaid": "^2.15.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.4.0",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.4.1",
    "ajv": "^6.10.0",
    "babel-loader": "^8.0.0-beta.0",
    "typescript": "^3.3.3333",
    "webpack": "^4.0.0",
    "webpack-cli": "^3.2.3",
    "webpack-dev-middleware": "^3.6.1",
    "webpack-hot-middleware": "^2.24.3"
  }
}
```

At this point, I am not sure what is even causing the error.

EDIT: I ran `npm install -D babel-loader @babel/core @babel/preset/env webpack` to reinstall all of the packages and commented out the offending code in `loaderLoader.js` per [this commit](https://github.com/mitchellmorris/loader-runner/commit/ef20b05e5014bfc403a1aac8ef2e7d4696eb4337) in the `loader-runner` package. The error at the top is now gone, but all the errors at the bottom are still there. The server runs fine so far. I have a [repo on GitHub](https://github.com/1silvertiger/test) that will reproduce the error. Try `npm run build` and then `npm run server`.

Comment: Please post your error log as text.

Comment: Your code is very large and, for now, incomplete. I highly doubt the question can solely be answered given the code you gave - consider reading the guide on [creating an MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) so as to have some hints about what you can include to make the issue **reproducible**

Comment: I posted it as text. Should I convert it all to text?

Comment: Your error is coming from somewhere in your server code, that is not included here... I think the best option when asking for debugging help on such a large codebase is to create a minimal github repository that users can clone, inspect and debug. Would that be possible in your case?

Comment: I am trying that now. So you don't think it's an issue with Webpack/Babel, or it is an issue with them somewhere in the Node app?

Comment: Well, I can only *smell* the code, but yeah, `cannot read property 'default' of undefined` means that a module was imported but this module had no default export. And your module is your server code, so yup, I think we'll need your server code :)

Comment: Thanks for the help. I'm trying to create the issue in a smaller codebase. I looked at the file it's supposed to be getting it from and it has `module.exports` on the third line...

Comment: First of all you're passing a function parameter called module and that's a reserved word, rename it to _module then try to console.log(_module) to see if it's getting value, the error means module itself is undefined and you're trying to access a child of it

Comment: @MaStErNeWbIe That's from a node module.